# how to package html outside epub reading flow

Tags: epub, epub3

I have an epub3 book containing lengthy data tables. I use a thumbnail image of these tables with a link to the actual html file (the html files are included in the manifest).

When I click the link to display the html table itself; the ereader displays the table, but when I click the `back` button the reader goes the end of the book and seems to have lost its place in the navigation.

How can I fix this so the `back` button works as expected? 
I'm using Readium and Calibre.

Comment: When you say "back button", what are you referring to? The little < on the left side of the screen?

Comment: I guess it depends on the ereader, but I mean that I right-click the mouse and select 'back' (like the back button on a browser, not the previous page in a page sequence, but the previous location). I think the `<` goes to the previous page.

Comment: don't forget about ebooks.stackechange.com for these types of questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't your ePub file: it's the fact that the Readium interface doesn't render books like a typical web page... So the back button on your browser won't behave correctly.

The best solution I have found is to create your own back button using an inline link:

`<a href="[chapterFile].xhtml#[elementID]" class="fakeButton">Go Back</a>`

This will take you back to the targeted element in the specified chapter!